# How to add "subsection head" to the Mini Frame Navigation (Berlin)

Tags: beamer, navigation

The default of the Mini Frame Navigation (Berlin) only contains "section head".

I want to **add the "subsection head"**, such as the following picture:

[image: yujBPH.md.jpg]

My code is:

```
%! Tex program = pdflatex
\documentclass[UTF8,10pt]{beamer}


\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usetheme[compress]{Berlin}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\setbeamerfont{font of headline by me}{size*={6}{1}}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}% 
{   
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \usebeamerfont{font of headline by me}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}



\begin{document}

\section{Sec}

\subsection{subSec1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frametitle of subSec1} 
Hello
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frametitle of subSec1} 
Hello
\end{frame}


\subsection{subSec2}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frametitle of subSec2} 
Hello
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

How to modify the above code to meet my requirement?

Thanks to all :)

Comment: How many different sections does your presentation contain?

Comment: @leandriis    only two sections